# How to manually add startup applications on Mint 17.3

Tags: linux, linux-mint, startup

I have fully updated Linux Mint 17.3.

I need to add a bunch of applications to startup.

The problem is, the following dialog doesn't work - It won't add me an application from the list, nor it will add any custom command.

[image: Startup Applications]

Anyway, there must be other way I can add those applications manually, probably by editing some startup file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found it at:

```
~/.config/autostart/
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that "autostart" can execute programs located specific place:

```
/usr/share/applications/
```

If you create link there, you can do that. Or you can use `xinit` start up script etc.

Comment: 1. HowTo find a programm location of in linux (Mint)? 2. And HowTo make that link?